# How to play ROS bag file frame by frame

Tags: ros

```
rosbag play bagfile.bag
```

ROS's bag player provides a nice tool to replay the data but it's kind of difficult for debugging as we can't control frame-by-frame play. I know it's possible to control replay speed by the `-r` option but is it possible to play it frame-by-frame? e.g in `rqt_bag` we can move frame by frame to see the value (although it can't publish the single frame).

How do you debug your program with ros bag file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start your bag in a paused state using

```bash
rosbag play bagfile.bag --pause
```

And then you can *step* through your bag by pressing the `s` key.
I believe each step is a message from the bag file.

Comment: Awesome:) It works well